# using flutter in VS code, how can i move entire widget up/down using keyboard?

Tags: flutter

I'm using VS code for Flutter and my codes are messed up

1. how can I move an entire widget
2. also, how can I move the properties inside the widget

because it is getting a bit messy with extended code to detect and relocate the widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select your entire widget/property and then press `alt + down arrow` keys to move your code.